# Break on document.write in a inline script with the chrome debugger API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a page with:

```
<script>document.write("bla")</script>
```

I like to create a chrome extension which logs the argument bla of document.write. I was planning using the debugger API, but it doesn't trigger:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url && !tab.url.startsWith('chrome://')) {
        
        attachDebugger(tab.id);
    }
});


function attachDebugger(debuggeeTabId) {
    chrome.debugger.attach({tabId:debuggeeTabId}, "1.0", function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
        }

        // Enable the Debugger
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:debuggeeTabId}, "Debugger.enable", {}, function() {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                return;
            }
            
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:debuggeeTabId}, "DOM.enable", {}, function() {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                    return;
                }

                // Set the breakpoint
                chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId:debuggeeTabId}, "DOMDebugger.setInstrumentationBreakpoint", {eventName: "document.write"}, function() {
                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log("Breakpoint set on document.write");
                });
            });
        });
    });

    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(debuggerEvent);
}

function debuggerEvent(debuggeeId, message, params) {

    console.log(message + " " + JSON.stringify(params));

    //let callFrame = params.callFrames[0];
    //let funcArgs = callFrame.scopeChain[0].object.description;
    //console.log("document.write called with arguments: ", funcArgs);
}
```

Chrome Devtools has an option to break on it via Event Listener Breakpoint - Parse - document.write but it is unknown how it is implemented.

I also tried `DOMDebugger.setEventListenerBreakpoint` without success.

Comment: Devtools source code says it uses `Document.write` (note the upper case letter). You can use Protocol monitor in devtools to see the commands it sends. I wonder though why you attach when the tab has already loaded and not beforehand...

Comment: Thanks that did it! How do I do it beforehand?

Comment: It depends on how you navigate to the site. If you do it explicitly then open a new about:blank tab first, attach the debugger and set up the breakpoint, then use chrome.tabs.update to navigate.